# How to display textarea value when print in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, print-preview

I'm create some form for some kind of slip and it will use browser printing service like chrome, firefox, and another browser but I can't see the input value when I print preview those form.

```
<textarea style="width:370px; min-width:370px; max-width:370px; min-height:100px; max-height:100px; height:100px; border:none; resize: none; overflow:hidden" placeholder="hello" ></textarea>
```

Javascript

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printdata");
        var newWin= window.open();
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        //newWin.close();
```

Comment: I am using chrome and while doing print preview I can see the values .

Comment: I'm checking all the css and create new one but still the same can't see the value but I can see placeholder